# How to add footer button in horizontal listview

Tags: android, listview, footer

I want to add an button to the footer of listview, I'm using horizontal listview, The **adapter class**:

```
public ItemAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to,0);
        this.layout = layout;
        inflator= LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }
```

I return the newView and bindView:

```
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {     
        View v = inflator.inflate(layout, parent, false);
        TextView footer = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, final Context context, Cursor c) {
        final int id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(ItemDb.ID));
        final String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ItemDb.NAME));
        }
```

and the activity class:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        String[] from = new String[] { ItemDb.NAME, ItemDb.CONDITION, ItemDb.EMAIL};
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.etItemName, R.id.etItemCondition, R.id.etEmail };
        itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item, null, from, to);
        this.setListAdapter(itemAdapter);
    }
```

How can I add the button in listview footer?
Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:background="@drawable/photo_frame"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imagedescription"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/condition"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/condition"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/condition"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/email"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Override `getCount()` of listview adapter to return `data.size()+1` elements;
2. In getView() insert something like this:

   if (position == data.size()){
       return getFooterView();
   }

In `getFooterView()` inflate proper layout with button.

Comment: Additionally have a look at this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924047/android-show-listview-between-header-and-footer

Comment: haha, just want to say not really understand what you mean..
thanks for the additional link, i try to study first. ^^

Comment: but I totally din't use listview, how can i apply **listView.addFooterView(footer);** in my case? >.<
I just have one xml.

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#headerfooter

Comment: Dont understand what you mean, in the vogella link you mention is an example does that not work for you?

Comment: yes.. or I don't how to apply in my case, cause it seem like a bit different with my case, I just use one xml to add the row horizontal listview.