# Listview scrolling according to the image button

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview .I disabled the scrolling in listview. I have 2 image buttons at the starting and ending of the listview. Now what i want is
1) By clicking those buttons the list view should move up/down accordingly and it should move one row up/down at each button click.
2) I don't know how to add the image buttons inside the listview. I tried of adding header and footer but i cannot. 
Any my layout needs to be like [image: ()]

As am a newbiew help me achieving the above two. I created my listview based on [this](http://www.debugrelease.com/2013/06/24/android-listview-tutorial-with-images-and-text/) link.
Thanks in advance

Comment: instead u should be using to image view with the match parent with it alignparentTop and alignparentbottom respectively. and then in betwwen then add the list view.

Comment: Can u please explain this with small example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `RelativeLayout` and put `listView` and two `ImageView`s as suggested by @Terril Thomas in comment. Also when listView is loaded you can perform an action on those buttons like

```
listView.smoothScrollToPosition("row_no");
```

for smooth scrolling, alternatively you can also scroll like

```
listView.setSelection("row_no");
```

you just have to do something like, if you click on **bottom image** then you need to **increment** the **number** and call `listView.smoothScrollToPosition("incremented number");` also check for condition `if("incremented number" < listView.size())` then only you have to scroll to that position. And for top image opposite to this i.e. decrement the **number** & check `if("decremented number" > 0)`, if true then scroll to decremented number!

For UI you may create a RelativeLayout and you can put:

```
<ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/scrollUp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>

<ListView 
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/scrollUp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/scrollDown"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</ListView>

<ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/scrollDown"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>
```

This will result into:

[image: This image]

Hope you got what I mean.

for more information on header and footer for `ListView` check for: [***this link***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924047/android-show-listview-between-header-and-footer)

Comment: Thanks for ur response. i need my imageviews to be on listview like in header and footer adding image views. But i don't know how to done this.And here that number means which one. Can u explain in detail please.

Comment: please go through updated answer. Also I mentioned "that number" = "incremented/decremented number", refer that too

Comment: I resolved img btn issue am trying with scrolling rows.Once i get the ans i let u know. And can u tell me after checking the condition how to scroll the position up/down